# Turn tree-sitter queries into folding

Tags: neovim, folding, plugin-treesitter

I have the following config in my `ftplugin/groovy.lua`:

```
vim.opt.foldmethod = "expr"
vim.opt.foldexpr = "nvim_treesitter#foldexpr()"
```

I simply want every region that constitutes a `block` to be folder. I'm not sure how to configure this is. I don't even know where to look in the help docs.

I have tried reading through `:help nvim_treesitter`. No information there :(

Answer (score 1):

Write a `folds.scm` file in the `query` folder for your language.

---

I am looking at the code: `.../nvim-treesitter/autoload/nvim_treesitter.vim`:

```
function! nvim_treesitter#foldexpr() abort
    return luaeval(printf('require"nvim-treesitter.fold".get_fold_indic(%d)', v:lnum))
endfunction
```

Ok, so there's a "get fold indicies" function - this makes sense, that's how `foldexpr` works (which I assume you are familiar with as that's documented well - `:help foldexpr`)

So let's find and go to the `nvim-treesitter/fold.lua` file. You can find it in the plugin at `.../nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/fold.lua`.

We trace the code backwards and find this interesting chunk

```
folds_levels = ...
...
  local matches = query.get_capture_matches_recursively(bufnr, function(lang)
    if query.has_folds(lang) then
      return "@fold", "folds"
    elseif query.has_locals(lang) then
      return "@scope", "locals"
    end
  end)
...
```

Ok, so let's find the `has_folds` function. No? It's not there? What the heck. I read through the `nvim-treesitter/queries.lua` file and realized that this is what I'm looking for:

```
for _, query in ipairs(M.built_in_query_groups) do
  M["has_" .. query] = get_query_guard(query)
end
```

And traced it backwards to this:

```
local function runtime_queries(lang, query_name)
  return api.nvim_get_runtime_file(string.format("queries/%s/%s.scm", lang, query_name), true) or {}
end
```

Which finally leads me to the folder: `.../nvim-treesitter/queries/groovy`. I added my query, and then reloaded the file:

```
[
 (block_comment)
 (command (block))
] @fold
```

and it worked!

Comment: Make sure your queries are in your runtimepath. Debug like so: `:lua= vim.api.nvim_get_runtime_file(string.format("queries/%s/%s.scm", 'groovy', 'folds'), true)`. And append to your runtime path like so: `:lua vim.opt.rtp:append(vim.fn.stdpath 'config' .. 'my_dir')`